# How can I manually transfer Liquidity to a contract?

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20, smart-contract-wallets, liquidity-provider

I'm doing a payment splitter that automatically splits the received money to some wallets. In the future, I want this money to go to the liquidity of a token. If I transfer directly to the token address would it go to the liquidity? Or is there any "special address" to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you need to send the funds to that contract's liquidity pair, then call *sync()*.

You can check the documentation of the DEX you are using to get it's *factory* address and then call the public function to get your *pair* address, if it exists. Keep in mind that if the DEX migrated liquidity to a different version you need to check it's UniswapV1Factory and  UniswapV2Factory.